# phaser page goes blank when redirected, but works if navigated directlly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, phaser-framework

Creating a game application in HTML 5 using jQuery Mobile and Phaser.js. I want to redirect the user to a game page once the user clicks on a button. I see a blank page once clicked and no error on chrome console. However, if I directly navigate to the game page, game loads. Any leads?

here's the click event

```
<a href="game.html" http-equiv="refresh" content="0" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-corner-all">Play Game</a>
```

here's game.html page

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>My Game</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/phaser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/boot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/preload.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/gametitle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/gameover.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {

            //Create a new game that fills the screen
            game = new Phaser.Game(1000, 1200, Phaser.AUTO);
            //game = new Phaser.Game(window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio, window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio, Phaser.AUTO);

            //Add all states
            game.state.add("Boot", Boot);
            game.state.add("Preload", Preload);
            game.state.add("GameTitle", GameTitle);
            game.state.add("Main", Main);
            game.state.add("GameOver", GameOver);

            //Start the first state
            game.state.start("Boot");

        })();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `http-equiv="refresh"` is for meta tag see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp for refresh use `<a href="javascript:location.reload()">refresh link</a>`

Comment: How are the url's of the page when clicking to the page and navigating directly?